# Why Invalid Syntax in Python Unittest

Tags: python, python-unittest

```
from mark_3 import * # import everything from my module
import unittest # This sets the testing framework and a main program

class TestJoeTree(unittest.TestCase):  # use a meaningful name
def testNoSolution(self):
    self.assertEqual(0, beginRunningMain(r"C:\Users\xxx\exampleNoAns.txt", "hit", "bem")

if __name__ == '__main__':
     unittest.main()
```

Hi, I am using Python 3 and I have difficulty to run this UnitTest Class.
However, I keep getting the error message and I do not know how to run this unittest class in command prompt.

Here is the screenshot: [image]

Can anyone guide me how to solve this error message? This is my 1st day using Python and I have spent hours searching for solution. Thank you.

Comment: You are missing a closing parenthesis on `self.assertEqual(...`

Comment: What are you using to edit your code? A good text editor or IDE will help you balance parentheses and braces. Also note for future questions, that you should copy and paste the entire error message here instead of posting a screenshot. This makes it much easier to redact sensitive information.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice, I was using IDLE Python Editor.. not very user-friendly for a beginner unlike Visual Studio..Which Python editor would you recommend?

Comment: PyCharm is very good. It provides all of the amenitites which you are used to from VS. The Community Edition is available for free.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were missing a parenthesis in the assertEqual function, and you are not indenting the method testNoSolution (I think it is a method because of `self`).

```
class TestJoeTree(unittest.TestCase):  # use a meaningful name
    def testNoSolution(self):
        self.assertEqual(0, beginRunningMain(r"C:\Users\xxx\exampleNoAns.txt", "hit", "bem"))
```

Comment: The indentation issue could be a copy and paste error and not formatting it here properly.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
def testNoSolution(self):
    self.assertEqual(0, beginRunningMain(r"C:\Users\xxx\exampleNoAns.txt", "hit", "bem")
```

is missing a closing parenthesis.